# Correct procedure for branching this TFS Team Project

Tags: tfs, branch, team-project

On our TFS Server, we have a Team Project called "Connect". The root folder for that Team Project contains the root of the web application project. I'm not sure if it was setup correctly, but what I'm trying to do is create a branch of the "Connect" Team project so there are 2 versions, 1 for Production, 1 for a new development/enhancement. What are the correct steps to get the right structure? So that we can work on the enhancement in one, and eventually merge it into the production branch....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do some restructuring here. At a minimum that is probably:

$/Connect

---------dev

---------main

Where dev and main will become your branches and contain all the code that is currently in the root.

I'd usually expect to see something more like

$/Connect

---------ConnectWeb

-------------------dev

-----------------------src

--------------------------Connect

-------------------main

-----------------------src

--------------------------Connect

where dev and main are the branches and Connect contains the files and folders currently in root.  By putting the branches in another folder (I called it ConnectWeb) you have the option of having multiple development projects within the same Team Project which allows you to manage a portfolio backlog in a single team project.

[Rename or move files and folders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181398.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I used the command line tool to rename and duplicate everything into the subfolders.